# How to get select option value inside table with cell id by Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, html-table, html-select

Using JSP I add table row with cells containing select option when add button is clicked. I need to get the selected option values from table cells to Javascript. Below I have added by JSP and  code..

Javascript

```
var maxID=0;     
function getTemplateRow() {
var x = document.getElementById("templateRow").cloneNode(true);
x.id = "";
x.style.display = "";

x.cells[0].id = "staffno_add"+ ++maxID;
x.cells[1].id = "name_add"+ maxID;

x.cells[2].id = "desig_add"+ maxID;
x.cells[3].id = "curloc_add"+ maxID;

x.cells[1].style.visibility="hidden";
x.cells[2].style.visibility="hidden";
x.cells[3].setAttribute('onchange', 'getData(this)');
x.cells[2].setAttribute('onchange', 'getData1(this)');
return x;
}

function addRow(i) {
    //var button=[];
    var k=i.rowIndex;
var t = document.getElementById("theTable");
  var rows = t.getElementsByTagName("tr");

var r = rows[parseInt(k)];
r.parentNode.insertBefore(getTemplateRow(), r);  

}
        var y1=null;
        var y2=null;
        function getData(dropdown) {
        y1=dropdown.id;
        y2=y1[10];
        alert("desig_add"+y1[10]);
        alert('curloc_add'+y2);
     var get_id = document.getElementById('curloc_add'+y2).getElementsByClassName("getit")[0].innerText;//need my selected option value here...
    alert(get_id); 
document.getElementById("desig_add"+y2).style.visibility = "visible";
}
function getData1(dropdown1) {
        y1=dropdown1.id;
     y2=x1[9];
        alert("name_add"+y1[9]);
document.getElementById("name_add"+y2).style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

JSP

```
<form name="myform">
 <tr id="templateRow" style="display:none">
<td>
<input type="text" readonly>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" readonly>
</td>
<td>
<select  class="getit">
    <option value="">None</option>
    <%for(x1=0;x1<arrList.size();x1++){%>
<option value="<%=arrList.get(x1)%>"><%=arrList.get(x1)%></option>
  <%}%>
</select>

</td>

<td>
<select  >
    <option value="">None</option>
    <%for(x1=0;x1<lenList.size();x1++){%>
<option value="<%=lenList.get(x1)%>"><%=lenList.get(x1)%></option>
  <%}%>
</select>
</td>
<td><input type="text" readonly></td>
<td><input type="text" class="datepicker"  style="background-color:  
 #fffa90"/></td>          
<td>
<input type="text" readonly>


</td>

<td>
<input type="text"  class="datepicker"  style="background-color: #fffa90"/>
</td>
<td><input type="text"   class="datepicker"  style="background-color:   
 #fffa90"/></td>
</tr>
<input type="hidden" id="total" name="total">
</form>
<tr onclick="addRow(this,);">
<td>

<input type = "button" id="insert" value="Add" >
</td>
</tr>`
```

I am new to JSP and Javascript.. I want get selected option value in script.